# ¿Obtener el parámetro de una ruta?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6, blade

Tengo esta ruta definida

```
Route::get('/users/cars/{id}', 'Front\CarsController@index')
->name('front.user.cars.list')->middleware('checkuser');
```

Dicha ruta al final devuelve una vista en blade

```
public static function index()
{
    return view('front.user.cars.list');
}
```

Esto al final me construye una ruta tipo esta /users/cars/15

Lo que intento hacer es dentro del fichero blade front.user.cars.list.blade.php obtener este **ID** (15).

He estado jugando dentro de blade con

Request->parameter()

Pero recibo en blanco.

Comment: Sería mucho mas simple obtener el parámetro de la ruta en el controlador y devolverlo junto con la vista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes pasar a la vista el parametro que necesitas, algo así por ejemplo

```
public static function index(){
    $id = 15;
    return view('front.user.cars.list', ['id' => $id]);
}
```

Comment: El parámetro lo recibe vía la URL entonces creo que le deberías indicar como capturar dicho valor

Comment: Si te refieres a como mostrar el valor en la vista, solo bastaria con {{ $id }}

Comment: Se refiere a que el valor es variable, puede ser 15, 55 o 40, etc, pues llega como parámetro en la ruta.

Comment: exacto es un parametro en la ruta...no se si en el controlador cuando cargo la vista tal como dice el compañero JGuerreroS se lo envio, y luego en la vista lo printo con {{$id}} ?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ si hermano efectivamente el valor de la variable puede ser cualquiera, solo es un ejemplo que le haya puesto 15

Comment: El valor de la variable no puede ser cualquiera, tiene que ser el del parámetro de la ruta. Hardcodearlo no sirve, tiene que ser dinámico.

Comment: Gracias a todos, con los distintos ejemplos lo he visto. Gracias